# window.confirm detection using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using confirm() function of **Javascript** in my application. I need to find out whether confirm box is present or not while clicking other button. How to detect whether confirmBox (window.confirm) is present or not using Javascript? How to remove confirmBox using Javascript?

Comment: Here's a clue, if any of your javascript is running the confirm box isn't there. Javascript is single threaded, and since `confirm()` blocks you're not going to be having any other JS events running at the same time, they'll be queued until the thread is free.

Comment: Its modal, when its displayed you cant click anything else ...

Comment: ya in we application we can't click anything else. But I am using phonegap/cordova to convert web application to mobile application. So when I click back button of mobile then it is causing problems.

Answer (score -1):

You could use,

```
if ('confirm' in window && typeof window.confirm === 'function' ) {
    /* Do your stuff here*/
}
```

This is what you expecting?

Comment: I hope not. `confirm` is supported since 1996, more or less. Moreover, in IE8 and below, `typeof window.confirm === "object"`. Neat, huh?